# Detect Bias in YOLO format object detection dataset

Tags: machine-learning, dataset, object-detection, data-analysis, yolo

I work on YOLO data annotation. I want to know how to detect bias in the data before training in this kind of datasets. What are the metrics and analysis methods needed to use to detect bias in annotated object detection datasets before the model training phase (yolo as an example)?